# Format label text which gets the value from slider - JS

Tags: javascript, formatting

I have a range slider and label which gets the slider's value divided by 18.86

the script is working just fine, but I need to know how to format the label to present the result in a currency format, if possible.

```html
<input id="fundvalueslider" max="1000000" min="0" step="1000" type="range" value="0" />
<br/>
<br/>
<label id="lumpsumamount">0</label>
<p>I want it to show $1,000,000.00</p>
<script>
fundvalueslider.oninput = function()
{lumpsumamount.innerText = fundvalueslider.value /18.86;}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a format function:

(this function is written by me, not copy from anywhere. it works with and without decimal point. use it freely)

2017/6/5 edited:
Code snippet modified to support IE. For IE compatibility, there are two things to note:

1. IE <= 11 doesn't support Number.isFinite.
2. IE <= 11, `input type=range` triggers `onchange` not oninput (for Chrome, Firefox, Edge)

```js
function formatNumber(value, precision) {
    var regex = /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?:(\.)\d+)?$)/g;
    return (+value).toFixed(precision || 0).replace(regex, function(a, b, c, d) {
            return d ? b+',' : b;
    });
}

fundvalueslider.onchange = 
fundvalueslider.oninput = 
function() {
   lumpsumamount.innerText = '$'+formatNumber(fundvalueslider.value /18.86, 2);
}
```

```html
<input id="fundvalueslider" max="50000000" min="0" step="1000" type="range" value="0" />
<br/>
<br/>
<label id="lumpsumamount">0</label>
<p>I want it to show $1,000,000.00</p>
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I need only 2 decimals and a prefix $.

Comment: I've mentioned it in my question. You just saved my life, Much appreciated

Comment: I am not sure why, but the formatNumber function is not working with Internet Explorer. Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me with Microsoft Edge 38.34393.0.0.  What's your IE version?

Comment: IE11 
11.332.15063.0